# Have anyone ever thought of continuous analog Turing machine?

Tags: continuity, turing-machines

Have anyone ever thought of continuous analog Turing machine? The machine adopts continuous (from R) the input data from the tape,
It moves to a different state depending on the value on the tape.
On the output tape Turing machine writes real numbers according to its program. Is it possible to construct a computer on these principles?

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-is-required-for-universal-analogue-computation) are relevant?

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath135/kmath135.htm). Quote:

> Suppose, instead, we define a machine whose "state" at any time t is a real number s(t), and the "tape" is magnetized with intensity m(x) at location x (where x is the real-valued distance from the starting position). The machine is initially set to the state s(0) = 0 and placed at location x = 0 on the tape, which has been "programmed" with some initial profile of magnetic intensities over a finite range of the tape. (I'm treating m(x) as an ideal continuous function.)

About the question: "Is it possible to construct a computer on these principles?", [analog computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) were invented before the digital ones. The problem is that infinite resolution isn't more possible than infinite tape.

Comment: As far as I know, those analog computers were not universal computers, but purpose-built for specific problems. The point of the Turing machine is that it is universal.

Comment: @celtschk, true. My point was that infinite resolution is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is possible to build a computer on that principle: Every integer is just a special case of a real number, and thus the continuous machine can emulate a standard Turing machine.

Or the machine could emulate a TM tape by simply treating every negative number on the tape as zero, and every positive number as one. It then would write only $-1$ or $+1$. Indeed, that's essentially how our digital computers work: Voltages and currents are continuous quantities (well, at least at today's dimensions of electronic components), and electronic components are also continuous in nature. However by using non-linear electronics, it is possible to interpret every sufficiently low value as 0, and every sufficiently high value as 1.